# C# web services

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new to web services. 
I was just following a tutorial and created a web service. The next step was to create a proxy by entering wsdl followed by path to esdl contract. It was supposed to create a `service1.cs` file however my system created `service.cs` file which was similar to except on the tutorial.

The next step is to create a console tester application. I added the `service.cs` file to my console project but it cannot compile. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error   1   
The type or namespace name 'Services' 
does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?)    
C:\.....\tws\Service.cs 4   18  tws
```

Please help.

Answer (score 18):

Did you look in the project references?

`System.Web.Services` is **NOT** in `System.Web` but in a different separate assembly.

See if there is a reference to :

```
  System.Web.Services
```

if not add a reference to:

```
  System.Web.Services.dll
```

Comment: thanx mate it did work... seems like i ve lot of learning to do

Comment: For those of you looking to still use this there is another library out there (Mvp.Xml) that can be used as a substitute. I learned this after several hours of trying to get NuGet package manager to install  System.Web.Services but could not find it. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

In your project System.Web.Services reference is missing to add this follow below

click on

```
References> Add References>  Assemblies > Framework >System.Web.Services
```

Either scroll the list to find this or type "System.Web.Services" in search box

select **System.Web.Services**   and add it .